# White Border Around Image

Tags: html, css

Currently working on a website and the whole time i've been struggling with the background image. I think it might be caused by the sidebar somehow(First website i've created that has a sidebar).
And now it for some odd reason has a white border around it.

Here's an image https://gyazo.com/d81f071f3e0d5b18020485565271557b

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'source_sans_prolight';
  src: url(font1/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.woff2) format("woff2"), url(font1/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansregular';
  src: url(font2/opensans-regular-webfont.woff2) format("woff2"), url(font2/opensans-regular-webfont.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'edoregular';
  src: url(font3/edo-webfont.woff2) format("woff2"), url(font3/edo-webfont.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #212121;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 0px 35px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 0px 35px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 4px 0px 35px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.logo {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 30px 10px 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2A2A2A;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2A2A2A;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: source_sans_prolight;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
.midheader {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.midheader h1 {
  font-family: edoregular;
}
.midheader p {
  font-family: open_sansregular;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: #fff;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: #3AC6F4;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: edoregular;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out;
}
.button1:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
.content1 {
  background-image: url(images/firstimgbk.svg);
  height: 1080px;
  outline: none;
}
.title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 850px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  font-family: edoregular;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding-top: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 5px #292929;
}
.title p {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 5px 2px #292929;
}
.arrow {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  -moz-transition: -webkit-filter .15s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter .15s ease-in-out;
}
.arrow:hover {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 2px black);
}
.content2 {
  height: 1080px;
  background-color: white;
}
.footer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-family: open_sansregular;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #2A2A2A:
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>Loom | Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="home" name="home"></a>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img alt="Logo" src="css/images/exloomd&c.svg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="midheader">
      <p>Check out my new website where our goal is to provide the cheapest most requested products!</p>
      <button class="button1">ExLoom Market
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footer">
        ©2016 ExLoom.
        <br>All Rights Reserved.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content1">
    <div class="title">
      hello
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">
      <img src="css/images/arrowdown.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content2">
    hej
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: need a link or screenshot please

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Edited the thread with an image :)

Comment: Do you mean the border because of the broken image?

Comment: The image isn't broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default most browsers give the `<body>` element a margin. Remove it with:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```